# SNMP on android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, protocols, snmp

I Want to fetch system resources of a computer like System uptime,Free HDD space,CPU usage etc in the Network Using SNMP protocol on Android Emulator through Code.How to achieved it ??? How to start Coding for SNMP protocol ??

Answer (score 1):

[this](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/snmp-manager_gqjz.html) should be useful

Comment: Actually i dont want any application in order to fetch the System resources.I am not getting how to start coding for SNMP protocol on Emulator. Is there any Api or wht ?

Comment: Plz Somebody help,I am in big trouble..:(

Comment: so you want to create MIB,OID etc??

Comment: Ya,u can say that,i want to send OID's of all the system parameters through code so that its MIB's will be retrieved which will contain their values.